How do I resolve Gradle sync issues
I keep getting Gradle sync failure few seconds after Gradle sync is loading on my android studio
I tried restarting over and over again, invalidate the cache and restarting again, uninstalling and reinstalling the android studio. Though the android studio I was able to download said it is Android studio Jellyfish.

So, what is the error message? Please also share the relevant parts of your gradle files that are connected to the error.

could not install Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8. Reason: ava.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Please [edit] your question to put all relevant information there instead of the comments. And while you're at it, please also share your gradle-wrapper.properties.


First of all please connect to the internet and sync again.
Secondly for simplicity use Gradle wrapper instead of local one.


Your answer should be able to solve the problem. This is way too generic to be of any help. We do not even know what the error is until the question is updated with more details. Please refrain from answering until it is sufficiently clear what is asked.

Sorry sir, just wanted to help

That's very kind of you, and that's actually what this site is all about, providing answers to questions. In this case, however, we do not have a clear question, so no adequate answer can be provided. When the question is updated you can edit your answer to address it more adequately. Thank you for your engagement, and welcome to the site!

could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/gradle-8. Reason: java.net.SocketTimedoutException: Read timed out

That might be network issue, you need to connect your computer to the internet
